# Why did Frank serve dinner after everyone was supposed to be asleep?

Tags: rocky-horror-picture-show, rocky-horror-show

Brief chronology of the film:

- Brad and Janet attend Hapschatt wedding
- Brad and Janet try to visit Dr. Scott;  get stuck at Frank's castle instead
- They meet Frank and co, see Rocky's "birth", and watch Frank murder Eddie
- Brad and Janet are shown to separate bedrooms for the night
- Rocky escapes, Janet finds him and they fool around, Dr. Scott shows up, Brad, Frank, and others discover Janet and Rocky *in flagrante delicto*.
- Frank decides to serve dinner
- Upon being informed that Eddie was the main course, Janet runs into Rocky's arms;  Frank gets jealous and chases her away;  Scott and Brad chase Frank.
- Frank freezes everyone except himself, Riff-Raff, and Magenta, dresses them up, and starts the floor show
- Riff-Raff and Magenta appear, and assume command from Frank;  Riff-Raff kills Columbia, Frank, and Rocky.
- Dr. Scott, Brad, and Janet flee the castle;  it returns to Transylvania;  the movie ends

The important part, for our purposes, is that dinner is served *after* everyone had gone to bed.  Granted, everyone got up and left their rooms, but no one knew that would happen in advance.  So Frank seems to have scheduled a dinner for five people (six, if he somehow anticipated the sudden arrival of Dr. Scott), and arranged for it to be served while four of the five guests were in bed.  Furthermore, it was a birthday dinner, and the birthday boy wouldn't have been present.

#### Why did Frank schedule dinner for after everyone went to sleep?

Comment: You are trying to make sense of the Rocky Horror Picture Show?

Comment: What? No spoiler alerts?

Answer (score 3):

It reflects the order of the invitations Frank extended earlier, during "Sweet Transvestite":

> Why don't you stay for the night? (Night!)
>   Or maybe a bite? (Bite!)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that Frank's libido would allow him to imagine that everyone has gone to bed to sleep - just some frenzied coupling and then everyone to the dining room for some post-coital birthday cake. Frank's well travelled enough to know that everyone will be peckish after a romp, so knew there was no need to announce it.

Also he's an insane, sexy party animal who operates by his own mad logic!

Tangentially - people in the 16th century actually did this, or something similar. They tended to go to bed earlier than us, sleep awhile then wake and occupy themselves for an hour or so - food, sex, reading etc, then return to bed to sleep until morning.

How long has Dr Frank been on Earth?

http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/magazine-16964783